# useSWR mutate function not working as expected

Tags: reactjs

mutate function not working as i expected, when sharing same state with other components

expect:
every mutate call by clicking button, re-fetch original data, so i can find new post.json request on networkTab

working: but, every mutate call, not fetch new data. i couldn't find post.json on networkTab
if i remove Item.js file, it works as i expected.(every mutate-call, every re-fetch)


why this happening?

```
//App.js

import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import useSWR from 'swr'
import ItemList from './ItemList';

function App() {
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    console.log('rerender')
  })
  const fetcher = async(urlKey) => {
      const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const result = await response.json();
      return result
  }
  
  const {data,error,mutate} = useSWR('/get/posts',fetcher); 
  
  const updateFetch = () => {
    mutate({},true); 
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <ItemList/>
        <button onClick={updateFetch}>reFresh</button>    
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
//ItemList.js
import React from 'react'
import useSWR from 'swr';

function ItemList() {
  const {data,error} = useSWR('/get/posts');

  return null
}

export default ItemList
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to docs:
broadcast a revalidation message globally to other SWR hooks using the same key by calling `mutate(key)`.

i.e You have to tell `mutate` which Api data you have to fetch again in your case. It would be like this:

```
mutate('/get/posts',true)
```

I have created this sandbox for reference: https://codesandbox.io/embed/reverent-cloud-fhm2w